# Robotium. waitForActivity() returns false for embedded activity in TabHostActivity

Tags: java, android, robotium, ui-testing

I have a TabHostActivity that has 4 tabs (and 4 corresponding Activities). When in the test I click on one of `them("Search")` the SearchActivity should appear (and it actually does). The problem is that in Robotuim-test I try to wait for this activity using `solo.waitForActivity()` and it fails even if the Activity is on the screen. Also all view of this activity are not available via `solo.getView()` - returns nulls.

Answer (score 1):

If `solo.waitForActivity()` doesn't work, you can use `solo.sleep(time)` and followed by `solo.assertCurrentActivity("not desired activity", Activity.class)` to confirm that you are in desired activity. And you can continue with further action performance.

Answer (score 0):

Tabhosts and robotium do not mix very well, basically the solo.waitforactivity only expects one activity to be open at a time but with tab hosts bad things happen where multiple activities are actually open and it gets confused.